# Linq to SQL With Left Outer Join and Group By With Sum - How To

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, t-sql

I'm trying to transform the SQL Query below into Linq to SQL

```
select Categorias.IdCategoria, Categorias.Nome, SUM(lancamentos.valor)
from   lancamentos
left outer join Categorias on Lancamentos.IdCategoria = Categorias.IdCategoria
where  Month(DataLancamento) = 11
and    Credito = 1
and    Lancamentos.Ocultar = 0
group by Categorias.IdCategoria, Categorias.Nome
```

This is what I've done

```
from    lancamento in Lancamentos
where   lancamento.Credito == true
&&      lancamento.Ocultar == false
&&      lancamento.DataLancamento.Month == 10
join    categoria in Categorias on lancamento.IdCategoria equals categoria.IdCategoria into temp
from    lancamentoJoinCategoria in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
group   lancamentoJoinCategoria by new { lancamentoJoinCategoria.IdCategoria, lancamentoJoinCategoria.Nome } into x
select  new {
        IdCategoria = (int?)x.Key.IdCategoria
        , Nome = x.Key.Nome
}
```

How do I add the SUM(lancamentos.valor) to the linq to sql above ?

Comment: I don't understand the Join you want to do. The way you formulated it you want to have the sum for lancamentos, even if no categoria exists for these lancamentos. So you would get an additional result row like "NULL, NULL, 42378" for all uncategorized lancamentos, right?

Is that really your intention or do you want rows like "24, SomeName, NULL" for all empty Categorias?

Answer (score 0):

It will be:

```
(from lancamento in Lancamentos
join categoria in Categorias on lancamento.IdCategoria equals categoria.IdCategoria into temp
from lancamentoJoinCategoria in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()

where lancamento.Credito == true
&& lancamento.Ocultar == false
&& lancamento.DataLancamento.Month == 10

group lancamento by new { lancamentoJoinCategoria.IdCategoria, lancamentoJoinCategoria.Nome } into x
select new
{
    IdCategoria = (int?)x.Key.IdCategoria,
    Nome = x.Key.Nome,
    sumValor = x.Sum(a=>a.valor)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You use the .Sum() method.

Eg;

```
Public Sub LinqToSqlCount03()
    Dim q = (From o In db.Orders _
        Select o.Freight).Sum()

Console.WriteLine(q)
End Sub
```

Comment: Pace, I know I have to use the .Sum() method. But how would I add that to the query that I showed ?

Answer (score -1):

according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx) there is no query expression equivalent to the Sum() operation.
I provided a little sample how you could use the Method Syntax of Sum() in a query.

> Some query operations, such as Count
>   or Max, have no equivalent query
>   expression clause and must therefore
>   be expressed as a method call. Method
>   syntax can be combined with query
>   syntax in various ways. For more
>   information, see [LINQ Query Syntax versus Method Syntax (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx).

```
var example = new[]
    {
        new { Count = 1, Name = "a" }, new { Count = 2, Name = "b" },
        new { Count = 2, Name = "c" }, new { Count = 2, Name = "c" }
    };

var result = from x in example
                select new 
                {
                    x.Name, 
                    Sum = (from y in example 
                           where y.Count.Equals(2) 
                               && y.Name==x.Name
                           select y.Count).Sum()
                };
var distinct = result.Distinct().ToList();
```